# Question about composite indexes and WHERE + GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, index-tuning

Alrighty so I understand how composite indexes work with WHERE but what if a column in the middle of the index is in the GROUP BY, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
      `a` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `b` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `c` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      INDEX(`a`,`b`,`c`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8';
```

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = ? AND c = ? GROUP BY b
```

Would MySQL stop using the index before `c`, or would it be able to use all three indexes in the above query since `b` is in the GROUP BY.  I haven't been able to find any resources on how exactly GROUP BY utilizes a composite index in a case like the above.  In this case I'm using MySQL for database flavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index isn't covering since `B` isn't part of the `WHERE` clause as a predicate, so the index is not applicable to this query. In other words, the index stores the data sorted by `A` then by `B` then by `C`, but since you're only filtering on `A` and `C`, there's no direct way to seek out `C` without `B`. You might end up seeing an index scan or table scan get used instead, in this case.

Comment: Only reason I'm confused is that if I did:

SELECT * FROM test WHERE a = ? AND b = ? GROUP BY c

The index on C is used to speed the group by, so GROUP BY can use the index, which is why I wasn't sure exactly sure if the conditions in GROUP BY constitute being part of the predicate or not

Comment: @MasonStedman The difference in that scenario is the order of columns in the index. Again the index is saving the data in order of A then B then C. As long as the columns you're filtering on (in your WHERE clause) is any continuous subset of the columns, reading from left to right, the index will be applicable. So an index on A then B then C is applicable to a query with WHERE A = ? AND B = ?. It's also applicable to WHERE A = ?. It's also applicable to WHERE A = ? AND B = ? AND C = ?. It is not applicable to a query with WHERE A = ? AND C = ?. You would need a separate index on A,C for that.

Comment: Actually I just found applicable documentation and it says you are incorrect, and that a tight index scan does still apply if the gap in indexes is bridged by GROUP BY or visa versa unless I'm reading it incorrectly

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: This is regardless of what columns are in your GROUP BY, or if you're even using a GROUP BY clause at all.

Comment: @MasonStedman Nothing in your linked documentation disagrees with what I said. I simply just explained how indexing works and when an index seek is used. For all intents and purposes, index seeking is the performant operation usage of an index. Otherwise when an index isn't applicable to seek on your predicates, a scan must occur as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Gotcha I misunderstood what you were saying regarding seek vs scan

Comment: @MasonStedman No problem, sorry I should've been more clear on that distinction. But yes in the context of appropriate index creation / tuning, you should concentrate on the predicates (JOIN, WHERE, and HAVING clauses) to ensure optimal performance will occur with appropriate operations like Index Seek. GROUP BY is a clause of the query which can benefit from being part of the index but it doesn't guarantee the index can be used or is applicable in a performant way unless the index already covers the predicates of the aforementioned clauses.

Comment: @J.D. - I disagree with it "not being covering".  "Covering" means that all the columns being used in the query are in the index.  I agree that it is not optimal.  Having the `WHERE` columns first `(a,c,b)` or `(c,a,b)` would be better.  The benefit of "covering" is that it avoids bouncing between the index's BTree and the data BTree.

Comment: I doubt if `HAVING` factors into indexing -- unless the Having clause can actually be moved into `WHERE`.

Comment: @RickJames "*I doubt if `HAVING` factors into indexing -- unless the Having clause can actually be moved into `WHERE`*" - Since when I wrote this answer ~2.5 years ago, I've grown to learn `HAVING` clauses matter much less with indexes, but there are edge cases that can benefit still. It's just less common than the `JOIN` and `ON` clauses, and so I don't tend to mention that anymore.

Comment: @J.D. - Yeah, `ON` is more similar to `WHERE` than `HAVING`.  The columns in `HAVING` _do_ count in "covering".  In `JOINs`, the big variation is "which table will the Optimizer decide to start with".

Answer (score 3):

Start with the `=` parts of `WHERE`:

```
INDEX(a, c,   [to be continued]
```

Those can be in either order.

Now continue with the `GROUP BY`:

```
INDEX(a, c, b)
```

Based on what you have shown us, that will be covering.  (That is, *all* the needed columns anywhere in the query are in the index.)

See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: TY That article was a really good explanation